# Continuous problems setting up oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-01652

I am currently embroiled in a battle of wills regarding the installation and setup of oracle 10.2.0.

I am following [this guide](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/admin/creatingdbmanually.html). Having received errors at every step of the way I've finally got to the very end of the guide only to receive this error message after running catproc.sql:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Package body created.

No errors.

Package body created.

BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 13210
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 13517
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15859
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15901
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REGISTRY", line 560
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REGISTRY", line 612
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL>
```

To get this far I had to modify my init.ora file with the following settings:

```
control_files = (C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\ora10\control01.ora,
                 C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\ora10\control02.ora,
                 C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\ora10\control03.ora)
undo_management = auto
db_name         = ora10
db_block_size   = 8192

db_cache_size=67108864
large_pool_size=1048576
shared_pool_size=117440512
```

My 'create database' command is the same as listed at [1](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/admin/creatingdbmanually.html) but with my datafiles in C and not D.

And please remember I am not a DBA and these values are simply plucked from various problems others have had around the 'net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you create the database with the [Oracle Database Creation Assistant](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/install003.htm) due to your lack of knowledge on Oracle database creation. It's good enough for most cases.

The problem in the link you provide is that **ALL** the settings are vey low. Sooner or later you'll see other problems regarding `UNDO` segment because of the little datafiles.

Anyway, the sentence says:

```
 default temporary tablespace temp
        tempfile 'c:\oracle\databases\ora10\temp.dbf'
        size 10M;
```

It's saying that the `TEMPFILE` tablespace is 10MB with no extend. You can try to add the `autoextend on` to become:

```
 default temporary tablespace temp
        tempfile 'c:\oracle\databases\ora10\temp.dbf'
        size 10M autoextend on;
```

Or because you have already created the tablespace you can execute:

```
 alter tablespace temp 
     add tempfile 'c:\oracle\databases\ora10\temp02'.dbf' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON
```

With this sentence you are saying: add another tempfile to the `TEMP` tablespace with size 10M (very little!) and make it bigger as needed.

From your link, also be careful with:

- The `character set WE8ISO8859P1`, I recommend you to use `UTF8`.
- The `logfile`s  sizes can do the database very very slow they have to be bigger.
- The parameter `db_cache_size` is only 67MB, very very little. The others too.

Anyway, the best way to start is using the [Oracle Database Creation Assistant](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/install003.htm).

Comment: Thanks, anything else I need to be aware of?